# Determining transversality

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, transversality

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x,y)=(x^2+x-2y^2+1,-x^2+y^2+3y-2)$. I am trying to show that the graph of this function is transversal to the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,y,x,y)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$.
To do this, I want to show that the sum of the tangent spaces of each manifold at every point in their intersection equals $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now, the tangent space of $f$ is the image of the Jacobian of $f$.The Jacobian of $f$ is given by 
$df=\begin{bmatrix}
    2x+1 & -4y \\
    -2x & 2y+3  
\end{bmatrix}$. The tangent space of the graph of $f$ is the image of this map. It appears that $df$ will always be full rank regardless of the choices for $x$ and $y$.

However, I am confused about what the intersection should look like and how to make sure the sum of the tangent spaces is as desired. What should I do?

Comment: How can the tangent space of the graph of $f$, which is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$, be the image of the map $df$, which is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: So then we can represent the graph of $f$ as $\{(x,y,z,w)\mid z=x^2+x-2y^2+1,w=-x^2+y^2+3y-1\}$, and the image of the jacobian of this would then be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I would still be somewhat careful. The terminology "Jacobian" is applicable to an explicit map (from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^l$), not to a manifold that is defined implicitly by giving equations. If you want to use a Jacobian to figure out the tangent space of the graph given by the implicit equations in your comment, you should probably give an explicit map defining that graph.

Comment: Something like $g(x,y,z,w)=(x,y,x^2+x-2y^2+1,-x^2+y^2+3y-1)$?

Comment: That looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of the graph of $f$ (I'll denote this by $G(f)$) and $\Delta$ is the set of all points in the diagonal $(x,y,x,y)$ such that 
$$x=x^2+x-2y^2+1,\qquad y=-x^2+y^2+3y-2.$$
Solving this, you obtain 
$$G(f)\cap\Delta=\{(1,1,1,1),(-1,1,-1,1)\}.$$
From here it is just linear algebra:  We want to show that for each $x\in G(f)\cap\Delta$, the map $T_xG(f)\oplus T_x\Delta\to T_x\mathbb R^4$, $(u,v)\mapsto u+v$, has full rank.  The tangent space of $G(f)$ at $(x,f(x))$ is the set of all vectors $(u,df_xu)$, where $u\in T_x\mathbb R^2$, and the tangent space of $\Delta$ at $(x,x)$ is the set of all vectors $(v,v)$, where $v\in T_x\mathbb R^2$.

Thus, we need to show that the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}I_2& I_2\\df_{(1,1)}&I_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}I_2& I_2\\df_{(-1,1)}&I_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
are full rank, where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

Comment: Does the second part come from writing the graph of the function as a function itself as I wrote in the comments above, and then taking the Jacobian of that?

Comment: Yes (more characters)

Comment: Also, this shows that the Tangent space of $G(f)$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ at every point of intersection. But why does this imply transversal? Don't we need the sum of both tangent spaces to equal $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: No, it shows that the tangent spaces of $G(f)$ and $\Delta$ span $\mathbb R^4$ at every point in their intersection, which is precisely transversality.

Comment: And wouldn't the Jacobian matrices have the 0 matrices instead of the identity matrices? For example, using the $g$ defined above in the comments, the third entry in the top row should be the derivative of the second component $g_1=x$ with respect to $z$, which is $0$

Comment: Think of it like this:  What is the matrix of the map $(u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2)\mapsto(u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2, 3u_1-4u_2+v_1,-2u_1+5u_2+v_2)$?

Comment: I am confused why you are choosing that map.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I think the map above should be $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^4$ (just drop the $(z,w)$ in the domain).  Then $dg=\begin{pmatrix}I_2\\ df\end{pmatrix}$, and the have $h:(x,y)\mapsto(x,y,x,y)$ has pushforward $dh=\begin{pmatrix}I_2\\ I_2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I am not sure how you came up with the expression $(u1,u2,3u1−4u2,−2u1+5u2)+(v1,v2,v1,v2)$ above. Is that what you are talking about? Or are you talking about the function $g(x,y,z,w)=(x,y,x^2+x−2y^2+1,−x^2+y^2+3y−1)$

Comment: The expression $(u_1,u_2,3u_1−4u_2,−2u_1+5u_2)+(v_1,v_2,v_1,v_2)$ comes from an understanding of the tangent spaces.  The tangent space of $G(f)$ at the point $(1,1,1,1)$ is all vectors of the form $(u,df_{(1,1)}u)$ (hence the $(u_1,u_2,3u_1−4u_2,−2u_1+5u_2)$) and the tangent space of $\Delta$ at any point is all vectors of the form $(v,v)$ (hence the $(v_1,v_2,v_1,v_2)$).

Comment: For the tangent space for $G(f)$, is this equal to the image of the jacobian of $g$?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Right, so then my question is shouldn't the jacobian have all 0's in the top right and bottom right blocks?

Comment: Yes.  As you defined $g$ in the comments (as a map $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$) the last two coordinates are pointless.  So just consider it as a map $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^4$, and then $dg$ is (sort of) a $4\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: But then wouldn't that automatically be full rank due to the top block being the identity matrix?

Comment: No.  If $f$ where the identity map, then $G(f)$ and $\Delta$ are not transversal.

Comment: If your answer is incorrect as stated above, could you please update it? I am getting confused by the comments now. Thanks.

Comment: My answer is not incorrect, you're just thinking about it too hard.  Once you know what the tangent spaces of $G(f)$ and $\Delta$ are, it's just linear algebra.

Comment: But The matrices given above are $4\times 4$ matrices, not $4\times 2$.

Comment: I edited my answer to (hopefully) make things more clear.  Let me know if it helps.